# Is it possible to run Managed custom action which is written by .net 2.0 in WIx 3.0 on a machine which only installed .net 4?

Tags: .net, wix, wix3

I am using Wix 3.0 and developed a managed custom action which dotnet
framework version is 2.0.

Now, I faced a problem. This custom action can not be run in dot net 4.0
only machine, say WinXP SP2 + dotNet 4.0.

(For a managed EXE application, I can add app.config to indicate the
supportedruntime with 2.0 and 4.0. But for Wix 3.0, I do not know how to
solve it.)

I do not want to upgrade Wix 3.0 to 3.5.

Is there solution for this issue?

Comment: Why not install 2.0/3.5 frameworks? They all happily coexist.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a strong dependency of the managed Custom Action you have developed and the .Net Framework 2.0. If I were you I would consider the next:

- WiX v3.0 doesn’t have anything to do with this problem.
- .Net Framework 2.0 **is a base prerequisite** for the installer.
- .Net Framework 4.0 **is not a prerequisite** for the installer.

Summary: I suggest to add a Condition in the installer to validate the existence of .Net Framework 2.0. For that purpose you can use the 'NetFxExtension'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it seems this is the best solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there solution for this issue?

Yes, document that .NET 2.0  is a prerequisite for your installer. You can [add a check for the .NET version](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_for_dotnet.htm) in your installer, so that it fails with a clear error message if necessary.

Also note that anything older than Windows XP SP3 cannot run .NET 4, and anything newer already comes with .NET 2.0 installed out of the box. Therefore, the situation that you describe (.NET 4.0 installed but not .NET 2.0) can only occur on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Windows Server does not necessarily have any specific version of .Net installed.

Comment: @Gabe: I forgot Windows Server 2003, which indeed doesn't come with .NET 2.0 preinstalled and is the oldest server version supported by .NET 4.0. But newer Windows Server versions always come with .NET 2.0 preinstalled. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Comment: Although rare, Windows 2008 Server Core installs with no .Net (2008 R2 may remedy that).